# ui-calender : event not including end date if time is less than 9 am

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fullcalendar, angular-ui

I am using angular ui calendar plugin which uses fullcalendar to display events on a calendar. I am encountering a bizare result. If the the event ends before 9 am the end date is not included by the event rendered.

These are my two events :

```
 $scope.staticEvents = [
    {
      title: 'Static 1', 
    end: new Date(2015, 10, 30, 8, 30, 0, 0),
    start: new Date(2015, 10, 26, 8, 0, 0, 0)

    },
     {
       title: 'Static 2', 
      end: new Date(2015, 10, 30, 9, 0, 0, 0),
      start: new Date(2015, 10, 26, 8, 0, 0, 0)
      }
  ];
```

please find the code here : [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BaSMenlABfKLecxLfPPJ?p=preview)

How to include the end date of the event in this scenario ? Is anything missing in the code ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the nextDayThreshold is set to 9 AM by default in fullCalendar. You need to reset it to 12 AM.

More info [here](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/nextDayThreshold/)

You set this option in your controller like this:

```
$scope.uiConfig = {
  calendar:{
  nextDayThreshold:'00:00:00'
  }
};
```